# How to test if the app is presenting a certain view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm pretty new to XCode UI tests and I'm trying to run a test where I fill two text labels and then I press a button. After the button is pressed the app should make an URL call and be redirected to another view controller. I want to check if at the end of this operation the second view controller is displayed.

To test this, I have written the following test:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
    
let ownerTextField = app.textFields["ownerTextField"]
ownerTextField.tap()
ownerTextField.typeText("UserA")
let repositoryTextField = app.textFields["repositoryTextField"]
repositoryTextField.tap()
repositoryTextField.typeText("AppB")
app.buttons["SearchButton"].tap()
XCTAssertTrue(app.isDisplayingResults)
```

Where `isDisplayingResults` is

```
extension XCUIApplication {
    var isDisplayingResults: Bool {
        return otherElements["resultView"].exists
    }
}
```

I have set up the identifier of the View controller inside its swift file class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.accessibilityIdentifier = "resultView"
    ...
```

Nonetheless to say, the test fails. How can I get a success?

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple.
If after clicking the URL, Viewcontroller is presenting means your previous VC button doesn't exist on screen.
So Just **check for previous VC button exists or not.**

```
  If app.buttons["SearchButton"].esists() 
 { //write if code
 } else {
// Write else code
        }
```

Comment: Uhm that might work but it is not exactly what I am looking for. I tried to XCTAssert(app.buttons["SearchButton"].exists) and the test gets passed but it doesn't make any sense: after I press the button I should be redirected to a second screen so the button shouldn't exist anymore. What am I doing wrong?